# How to create a multidimensional array from a one dimensional array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an array:

```
a=['hello','shivam','how','are','you']
```

... and I want to make it into a multidimensional array like this below:

```
[['hello','shivam'],'how',['are','you']]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What determines which parts go into inner arrays? How do we know that `'hello'` and `'shivam'` go into an array, `'how'` doesn't, ...?

Comment: Your second array is not really multidimensional because it needs to be an array of arrays, and you have an array with arrays and a string.

Comment: That's what i am asking how to create such program in ruby. if want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def transform ar
  [ [ar[0], ar[1]], ar[2], [ar[3], ar[4]] ]
end
```

this does exactly what you want to do, i cant do more if you dont share the plattern you want it to order...

Comment: yueah i wanna do this way exactly...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably gonna need to look into using the [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) method:

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = [4,5,6]

a.zip(b)
 => [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Although this won't help you all the way, as you clearly have some singular array entries in there too.